# How to deal with 8UC3 and 8UC4 simultaneously in android ndk

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My code is working fine with showing brightness in the image using below code

```
   jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
   jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

   Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
   Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);
   vector<Mat> sChannels;
   split(mSrc, sChannels);

        for(int i=0; i<sChannels.size(); i++)
        {
            Mat channel = sChannels[i];
            equalizeHist(channel, channel);
        }
        merge(sChannels, bgra);
   env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
   env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);

   jint retVal;
   int ret = 1;
   retVal = jint(retVal);
   return retVal;
```

It work for me too for changing image into grayscale but in this way :

```
   Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
   Mat gray(height, width, CV_8UC1);
   Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);
   cvtColor(mSrc , gray , CV_BGRA2GRAY);
   cvtColor(gray , bgra , CV_GRAY2BGRA);
```

But when i am trying to use `bilateralfilter` with it , which only work with 3 channels as given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=bilateralfilter#bilateralfilter) , how to deal with it ? because java bitmap accept `RGBA` format ,and when i change the above into

```
Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)_in); 
Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)_in);
```

somehow bilateral filter show me output , but what if I have apply all these filter on one image ? how can I handle this problem ? because there may be other algorithms too which only deal with 3 channels.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert `CV_8UC3` to `CV_8UC4` you just need to call:

```
cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGR2BGRA);
```

since it outputs a 4-channel image (R, G, B and Alpha)

Inversely,

```
cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGRA2BGR);
```

should convert `CV_8UC4` to `CV_8UC3`

Comment: But `BGR` is not accpeted by java , isnt it ? if your using jni with android ?

Comment: yes it is, I have been developing Android+OpenCV apps with JNI in the past months and I have had to deal with this

Comment: can i send my resultant image as BGR to java ? and it accept it as bitmap ? because its not showing me output in this case , because my destination image is 8uc4

Comment: my image is working with bilatralfilter when i use `Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)_in); 
Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)_in);` but in the same program and to the same destination image i have to send the grayscale image too !!

Comment: that depends on what you need to do with the output `Mat`, because some processes need grayscale images, others BGRA and some work with 3 channels, like HSV images...so check the documentation and see if you are handling the `Mat` objects accordingly